# Plot statistical information of multiple recordings of experiments with Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, plot, seaborn

I have a randomized algorithm which I repeat several times, so I can evaluate it statistically. The dataframes from the experiments can be grouped to calculate the mean and median.

Now, I would like to plot the original information, along with the statistics I also calculated, with Seaborn. So I have up to 100 Dataframes with data like this.

```
module, coverage, timestamp
examples.monkey, 32.142857142857146, 1546513589.59586
examples.monkey, 35.714285714285715, 1546513589.609822
examples.monkey, 35.714285714285715, 1546513589.617172
...
util.container, 27.586206896551722 ,1546513594.559889
util.container, 27.586206896551722 ,1546513594.579989
util.container, 27.586206896551722 ,1546513594.598491
```

I can simply print multiple timeseries with lineplots as follows.

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
for df in dfs:
    min_timestamp = df['timestamp'].min()
    df["time"] = df["timestamp"] - min_timestamp

keys = ["Run " + str(i) for i in range(len(dfs))]
glued = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'run'})
ax = sns.lineplot(hue="module", x="time", y="coverage", ci="sd", units="run", estimator=None, data=glued)
plt.show()
```

This results in a plot like this:[image: Plot from different algorithm runs]

I can then calculate the mean and add it to the plot as follows:

```
sns.set(style="darkgrid")
for df in dfs:
    min_timestamp = df['timestamp'].min()
    df["time"] = df["timestamp"] - min_timestamp

keys = ["Run " + str(i) for i in range(len(dfs))]
glued = pd.concat(dfs, keys=keys).reset_index(level=0).rename(columns={'level_0': 'Run'})
sns.lineplot(hue="module", x="time", y="coverage", ci="sd", units="Run", estimator=None, data=glued)

means = glued.groupby(by=["module", "time"], as_index=False).mean()
means["run"] = "Mean"
sns.lineplot(hue="module", x="time", y="coverage", estimator="mean", palette=sns.xkcd_palette(["red", "black"]),  err_style="band", data=means)

plt.show()
```

However, the plot that results from this is rather useless. It looks like this.

[image: Plot from different algorithm runs with mean]

I would much rather be interested in something like the examples from seaborn, where my measurements are printed as an area, with the mean clearly visible. [image: Seaborn examples]

Now I suspect, that I get this ugly image, because the dataframe with the mean has much more datapoints. The algorithm takes measurements in random intervals, so the time stamps do not overlap most of the time. Since the measurements are so close together and a line is drawn between them, we get the picture of this broad stroke.

My concrete questions now are, whether a lineplot even makes sense here and also if it is the correct approach the calculate the mean myself beforehand?
If the approach is correct, how do I fix it, if not, what else do you use?

I also uploaded some sample results as csv files here in case you want to try: [1](https://pastebin.com/BR3gVh2P) [2](https://pastebin.com/LKdn98Ab) [3](https://pastebin.com/hNqkCDJE) [4](https://pastebin.com/FgKNEZZw) [5](https://pastebin.com/gn3qrcDn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using `lineplot` correctly in your second example. The whole point is to let seaborn calculate the statistics and plot the graph estimator ± ci for you. I don't see the point of calculating the mean in a dataframe, and then asking seaborn to plot the mean of the dataframe.

But anyway, your problem is that seaborn only aggregates y-values that have exactly the same x-value. From [the documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html?highlight=lineplot#seaborn.lineplot):

> By default, the plot aggregates over multiple y values at each value
>   of x and shows an estimate of the central tendency and a confidence
>   interval for that estimate.

As you correctly guessed, your values are too random and rarely overlap, which means that seaborn cannot calculate a meaningful mean. In my opinion, the solution is to decrease the time resolution of your measurements, so that all measurements taken in a period of (let's say) 0.1 time units have the same time-value, which will let seaborn average them together.

```
glued["roundtime"] = glued["time"].round(1)  # 1 significant digit
ax = sns.lineplot(hue="module", x="roundtime", y="coverage", ci="sd", estimator='mean', data=glued)
```

[image]

Comment: That's really great. I suppose I could also have 2 significant digits and somehow zoom into the plot.